# how to insert into a table based on look up

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, web-services, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a web service which inserts data in two tables

Customer

- ID
- Name
- Product ID

Product

- Product_ID
- Product Name

How to write a spring web service using jpa to insert into both the tables for the following scenario

- If a product already exists reuse the product ID and insert into the customer table

Again i just need an idea or sudo code on how to do it.

Thanks
Ridi

Answer (score 0):

fst, select the Product if it's exist?
if(!exist){
new Product and get Product id
}else{
get Product id
}
sec, insert into Customer.

I don't know if it will meet your needs completely，just have a look.

Comment: I am new to spring and spring JPA trying to understand but not able to do it. I am able to use it with a single table but not with the above use case. Again I really appreciate you taking time for answering this.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the product based on its **id** from database. If the fetch returns a result, use the returned product inside customer. Otherwise, create a new product and use it.

```
@PostMapping
public void insert(@RequestBody Request request){
    Product product = null;
    Optional<Product> productOptional = productRepository.findById(request.getProduct().getId());

    if(productOptional.isPresent()){
        product = productOptional.get();
    } else {
        product = new Product();
        product.setId(request.getProduct().getId());
        product.setName(request.getProduct().getName());
    }

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setProduct(product);
    // set remaining properties

    customerRepositoy.save(customer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you dale, I am new to sping so trying to understand your code. What does the Request object have? I created a POJO for Product and Customer but how do i determine a Request object? Could you please help me with a detailed code on how to achieve it or point me to something so i can take a stab at it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also when passing the Json what all information I need to pass

Comment: any help on this please?

Comment: The request body mostly depends on the business logic. For learning purposes you can use the Product and Customer POJO as request body. 

[This might help you](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/).

Answer (score 0):

use Transaction to avoid one insert and the other is not，when it comes exception.

```html
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public int insertProductToCustom(){
    Product product= null;
    product = selectProductFromDB();
    if(null == product){
        insertProductToDB(product);
    }
    Custom.setProductId(product.getId);
    insertCustomProduct(Custom);
}
```